# How to intercept/disable HTTP Trace Method in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, interceptor

In order to disable insecure http methods, I have used a request filter

```
@Component
public class MethodFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final String[] allowedMethods = new String[]{"PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"};

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (Arrays.stream(allowedMethods).noneMatch(x -> x.equals(request.getMethod()))) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for all methods except "TRACE".
For trace method, this filter is not invoked and I get a echo back of the all the headers in response body

```
TRACE /error HTTP/1.1
my-header: test
accept: */*
host: localhost:8087
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
```

For all other methods which are not in the list I get result as expected

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-11-03T11:49:48.545+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "DELETE method is not allowed",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

Referring to [doc](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.java#L463) it seems, trace requests are sent to frameworkservlet and processed there itself. Have tried setting `spring.mvc.dispatch-trace-request=true` but now the responses are clubbed like this (filter still not invoked)

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-11-03T11:49:48.545+0000",
    "status": 405,
    "error": "Method Not Allowed",
    "message": "TRACE method is not allowed",
    "path": "/test"
}TRACE /error HTTP/1.1
my-header: test
accept: */*
host: localhost:8087
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
connection: keep-alive
```

My question is how can I make TRACE response as same as the other requests ?

Note: The solution in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64810320/customize-spring-boot-http-trace-disabled-error-response) did not work for me.

**Edit:
Found the solution. An interceptor does the trick instead of a filter**

```
@Component
public class MethodInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final String[] allowedMethods = new String[]{"PUT", "POST", "GET", "OPTIONS"};

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (Arrays.stream(allowedMethods).noneMatch(x -> x.equals(request.getMethod()))) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
            response.setHeader("Allow", "PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS");
            response.setContentType("message/http");
            response.getWriter().println(request.getMethod() + " method not allowed");
            response.getWriter().flush();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And add the interceptor via config file

```
    @Configuration
    public class InterceptorConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            registry.addInterceptor(new MethodInterceptor());
        }
    }
```

This needs to be used in conjunction with `spring.mvc.dispatch-trace-request=true`

Answer (score 2):

What if you try configuring Spring Security for it ...
The approach with writing the filter manually, it feels a bit low level ...

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
     http
    .authorizeRequests()
       // You can actually disable other methods here as well
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.TRACE,"/**").denyAll()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

If this does not work for you ... according to the docs it says

```
Note that HttpServlets default TRACE processing will be applied
in any case if your controllers happen to not generate a response
of content type 'message/http' (as required for a TRACE response)
```

Why don't you try setting content type header to `message/http` when responding to a `TRACE` request in your filter ?

Another option is disabling this in the [dispatcher servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54306649/2599899)

Comment: Regarding Spring Security, want to do without it. Plus I don't want to enable authorization (anyMatchers is only available on this) since auth is taken care of separately.

Comment: As for message/http content type, you're right the documentation does say that however I have tried setting response.setContentType to this but the filter never gets invoked it seems.

Comment: And what if we try this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54306649/2599899

Comment: Tried that as well. Only method which can be overriden is the doService() and not doTrace() as mentioned. But I will try once again to see if I am not doing something wrong.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java.  There is no doTrace method here though. It is there on frameworkservlet

Comment: And what if we try this ? 

https://stackoverflow.com/q/64810320/2599899

Comment: That did not work as well however, I did it using interceptors. Thanks !

Comment: Can you post the solution in the edit to the original question ?

Comment: posted in the end of the question

Comment: Is that interceptor a  @Component or how do you integrate it with Spring MVC ?

Comment: Updated my ans. With @Component

Answer (score 0):

TRACE is currently disallowed by default, at least in Spring-Boot 3.1, since the default firewall WebSecurity uses StrictFirewall, which has as allowed methods DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST and PUT (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/492bde7808462dac36b399531f45a297bc212d69/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.java#L562)

This can be tuned easily with:

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    StrictHttpFirewall strictHttpFirewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    strictHttpFirewall.setAllowedHttpMethods(List.of(HttpMethod.GET.name(), HttpMethod.POST.name()))
    return (web) -> web.httpFirewall(strictHttpFirewall);
}
```